# Model bind two textfields into a dictionary as key-/value pair

Tags: c#, dictionary, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I have two textfields which I want to model bind into a dictionary. The first textfield should be the key and the second text field should be the value of that key.

In the view I have two fields like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDictionary.Key, null, new {@class = "form-control"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyDictionary.Value, null, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Instead of the .Key and .Value I want to know what should be placed here.

**What is the best way to implement this?**

Comment: We're going to need more context and details about where and when you are attempting to do this. What have you tried and why isn't it working?

Comment: If `MyDictionary` is a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` then it will have many keys and values. Are you attempting to access a specific item with a particular key to display in a textbox? Are you attempting to submit a form and bind it to a Dictionary item?

Comment: I have a for-loop which makes two textfields each iteration. Each iteration I want to bind a key-/value pair to the dictionary (so indexes are necessary). And at the end this dictionary is submitted indeed.

Comment: Make your model a `List<T>` where `T` is a model containing 2 properties  (and then its `@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Property1) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Property2) }`